# making capital letters a different colour in python

Tags: python

I'm making a python project on replit and would like to turn all the capital letters that are displayed red. Does anyone know how I would do this, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `termcolor` module. You can try something like this:

```py
from termcolor import colored

word = "Hello"
color = "red"

colored_str = ""
for letter in word:
    if not letter.islower():
        colored_str += colored(letter, color)
    else:
        colored_str += letter

print(colored_str)
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

There are more colors available, you can check the other colors there --> https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/.

I am not sure if the behaviour of this code will be the same in all machines. I am using a Linux Mint machine and it works perfectly!

Comment: thanks for the info. if I wanted to add in the following code where exactly would I put it ?                                                                                                                                      text = 'VEP HYXHLVHTP MO AWFJYFLT H RFNEPS HJNEHAPV FL VEFU' 
replaced_text = text.replace('V', 't')
print(replaced_text)

Comment: So you want to color all the letter but the "t"?